# How to convert from Virtual Key codes to System.Windows.Forms.Keys

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, key

If I intercept a key press using win32 calls, I now have a key code.  Is there a way to convert that to a System.Windows.Forms.Keys value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The integer values for System.Windows.Forms.Keys enum match that of the Win32 calls.

```
Keys keyData = (Keys)rawWin32KeyCode;
```

Comment: This is not working if some modifier keys (shift, ctrl., alt) are pressed! 
lParam.vkCode = 160 // = VK_LSHIFT
lParam.scanCode = 42
Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
key = Space | F17

Answer (score 22):

Use [`KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyinterop.keyfromvirtualkey).

Comment: If the int and char keycode are interchangeable then this previous solution should work: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544141/how-to-convert-a-character-in-to-equivalent-system-windows-input-key-enum-value/544245#544245">link</a>

Comment: The question was about WinForms; KeyInterop is a WPF class not available under WinForms