# How to convert a virtual-key code to a character according to the current keyboard layout?

Tags: c#, winapi

I have browsed several earlier questions about this, and the best answer I found so far is something like this:

```
(char) WinAPI.MapVirtualKey((uint) Keys.A, 2)
```

However, this doesn't work in two ways:

- It always returns capital letters. For `Keys.A` I expect to get the character `a`, while for `Keys.A | Keys.ShiftKey` I expect to get `A`; however, I seem to get `A` for both.
- It doesn't seem to take keyboard layouts into account. For example, for `Keys.OemMinus` I always seem to get the character `-`, even if the current keyboard layout is German, where I expect this key to return `ß`.

What is the correct solution for this?

Comment: You can check explicitly if the shift key is pressed and then adjust your character casing.

Comment: @Ben: Oh really? So what is the virtual-key code for the Cyrillic ф on the Russian layout then?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The correct solution is the `ToUnicode` WinAPI function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ToUnicode(uint virtualKeyCode, uint scanCode,
    byte[] keyboardState,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    StringBuilder receivingBuffer,
    int bufferSize, uint flags);
```

One way to wrap this into a sensible, convenient method would be:

```
static string GetCharsFromKeys(Keys keys, bool shift, bool altGr)
{
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    if (shift)
        keyboardState[(int) Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
    if (altGr)
    {
        keyboardState[(int) Keys.ControlKey] = 0xff;
        keyboardState[(int) Keys.Menu] = 0xff;
    }
    WinAPI.ToUnicode((uint) keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
    return buf.ToString();
}
```

Now we can retrieve characters and actually get the expected results:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetCharsFromKeys(Keys.E, false, false));    // prints e
Console.WriteLine(GetCharsFromKeys(Keys.E, true, false));     // prints E

// Assuming British keyboard layout:
Console.WriteLine(GetCharsFromKeys(Keys.E, false, true));     // prints é
Console.WriteLine(GetCharsFromKeys(Keys.E, true, true));      // prints É
```

It is also possible to use [`ToUnicodeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the characters for a keyboard layout that is not the currently active one. The signature is the same except for one extra parameter, the input locale ID, which can be retrieved using the [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: WinAPI.ToUnicode((uint) Keys.E, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0); Why Keys.E??

Comment: How do you get altGr state? `KeyEventArgs` has no such thing.

Comment: Ah, seems AltGr is simply ctrl + alt. Nice. This function is a life saver when overriding internal stuff and only having access to `KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: it's exactly what i want. thanks. it's good combination with MessageFilter in Raw Input.

Comment: Just FYI, I used to GetKeyboardState api from user32.dll to fill the keyboardState byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved using this method:

```
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
public static extern int ToAscii(int uVirtKey, int uScanCode, byte[] lpbKeyState,
        byte[] lpChar, int uFlags);
```

The example usage can be found here:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/toascii-function-t1706394.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, uint uMapType);

    private void textBox1_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = (char)MapVirtualKey((int)e.KeyData, (uint)2);
        if (char.IsNumber(c)) DoSomething();
        else if (!char.IsNumber(c)) DoNothing();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem in WinUI 3. I tried solving it using the approach from Timwi's answer, but I needed the actual keyboard state information. This is because I wanted to use it with a control that accepts keyboard input. To achieve this, I added another function to get the keyboard state directly.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(uint virtualKeyCode, uint scanCode,
    byte[] keyboardState,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)] StringBuilder receivingBuffer,
    int bufferSize, uint flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetKeyboardState([Out]byte[] receivingBuffer);

public static string GetCharsFromKeys(VirtualKey key)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new(256);
    byte[] keyboardState = new byte[256];
    KeyboardHelpers.GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

    _ = KeyboardHelpers.ToUnicode((uint)key, 0, keyboardState, buffer, 256, 0);
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

If you need more information about this function `GetKeyBoardState(PBYTE lpKeyState);` you can read this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate