# Custom DataGridView NumericUpDown editing control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, numericupdown

Follow-on from question here : [How to assign typical NumericUpDown properties to custom NumericUpDown based control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793400/how-to-assign-typical-numericupdown-properties-to-custom-numericupdown-based-con)

I'm trying to do something similar to this scenario but I don't want / need an entire column of `NumericUpDown` controls; I just need a custom `NumericUpDownCell`-type class that I can switch in to a specific TextBox cell in a `DataGridView`, use it for data-entry and then flatten it back to a plain `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` again.

So I'm using pretty much the exact same code as the example in the linked question (in terms of the classes `NumericUpDownCell` and `NumericUpDownEditingControl`) but instead of creating an entire column, I just want to take a single `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, dispose it and replace it with a `NumericUpDownCell`, á la :

```
Private Sub ConfigureField(activeRow As DataGridViewRow)
    Try
        Dim lowerLimit As Integer = 0
        Dim upperLimit As Integer = 50
        Dim cfgValueCell = dgv(myColumn.Index, activeRow.Index)

        cfgValueCell.Dispose()
        cfgValueCell = New DataGridViewCustomNumericUpDownCell With {
                                .Minimum = lowerLimit,
                                .Maximum = upperLimit}
        dgv(myColumn.Index, activeRow.Index) = cfgValueCell

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

But that throws an exception in the `Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl` for the class `NumericUpDownCell` :

```
Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex As Integer, initialFormattedValue As Object, dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
    MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
    Dim ctl As NumericUpDownEditingControl = CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, NumericUpDownEditingControl)
    ctl.Value = CType(Me.Value, Decimal)
    ctl.Minimum = Me.Minimum
    ctl.Maximum = Me.Maximum
End Sub
```

Specifically :

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl' to type
> 'PrototypeUI.NumericUpDownEditingControl'.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: An empty Try-Catch usually isn't a good thing.

Comment: Yup, do appreciate that @LarsTech, right now I'm just using the Try-Catch to capture exceptions while I'm writing/debugging. For what it's worth, the Try-Catch in the `ConfigureField` sub doesn't throw any exceptions; it's the `InitializeEditingControl` override sub in the custom derived class where the exception occurs (i.e. it seems I can dispose-and-replace the cell in the grid; it's only when I enter the new cell - thus initialise the EditingControl - that the quoted exception occurs?)