# Override Ctrl key in TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have a textbox ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>character</kbd> function and reassign a different use for the ctrl key?

Situation: I have multiple text boxes on a Form. Ideally I would like the textboxes to jump from one textbox to another after enter in a single character. However the textbox can have more than one input, in this case I want the user to hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to stay on the textbox while they enter in multiple characters.

Essentially, I want my <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (if held down) to stop the textbox from jumping.

I've tried using a combination of `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyUp` and `TextChanged` event to handle when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed, but in the end, I can't enter any data once the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down. Is there a way around this?

The reason for this is because 95 percent of the time its always 1 character. Therefore to quickly traverse through the textboxes, the user would hit a single character. However in the unlikelihood that the user wants to enter in 2 digits, they can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (So it doesn't jump to the next textbox) and enter in 2 digits as desired.

Comment: You can surely somehow convert `Ctrl`+`SomeKey` to char (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6929275/1997232), etc.), but are you sure in what you are doing? I sounds absolutely uncomfortable (for me) to type while having `Ctrl` pressed. It is unclear what scenario you are trying to implement and why `TextBox` change its focus after entering one character. Can you provide some code perhaps and explain it better? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: The first usability study you perform on your UI should be on your team mates. Hopefully they can speak freely and tell you what they think of it.  In the unlikely case that doesn't discourage you then at least pick a key that doesn't alter the character code.  Nobody ever has a good use for the ScrollLock key.

Comment: @ Sinartr - Please see edit for the reason behind this bizarre situation! :)

Comment: @Hans Passant - The UI team actually requested this. My original design was to allow the user to enter in as many characters they want in the textbox and hit tab or enter to move on to the next Textbox. Good suggestion regarding the ScrollLock key! Thanks :)

Comment: You said `digits`.  `Shift` seems like an easier key to work with.  Easy enough to turn `#` into `3`.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. How about using a timer set to something like 150ms? So that focus would only shift after the delay has elapsed and no additional character was entered during that time frame. If new character is entered reset the timer so it counts from 0 to 150ms again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the commenters said, there's probably a better way of doing this, in a UI sense. That you would press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to prevent switching textboxes is weird behavior. Having said that, using the following in KeyDown should get you what you were trying to do.

```
if (!(e.Control && char.IsLetterOrDigit((char) e.KeyCode)))
{
    return;
}

txtBox.Text += (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(e.KeyCode);
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Thank-you! This steered me in the right direction. Sorry for the late response, I was shifted to other projects.