# WPF KeyGesture with OEM keys

Tags: c#, wpf, input

OEM keys depends on the keyboard, that's ok. What I'm trying to accomplish is what Visual Studio does for a few shortcuts.

To focus on Solution Explorer, my shortcut is CTRL+ç (I'm using a Brazilian keyboard).

So, I've created a `KeyGesture` with `Key.Oem1` and the shortcut works just fine, however WPF shows CTRL+Oem1 in the `InputGestureText`. I want to show the actually character bound to Oem1 key.

```
var gesture = new KeyGesture(Key.Oem1, ModifierKeys.Control);
var text = gesture.GetDisplayStringForCulture(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
//'text' is CTRL+Oem1 and should be CTRL+ç
```

How can I get the actual character? I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31204719/1830639) but it uses WinForm Keys enum.

Comment: Just use your code from the snippet that uses the WinForm Keys enum. It's just using those to compare against modifier key state, and you don't care about those boolean outputs. So rip that code out, and you won't have any need for a WinForm reference.

Comment: That snippet does assume an input of a Virtual Key Code, though. Does KeyGesture give you that?

Comment: `WinAPI.ToUnicode((uint) keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);` WinForms Keys enum values are different from WPF Key enum values.

Comment: I never said that they weren't. The function takes a virtual key code as a uint, not a WinForm enum type.

Comment: yes, but the code just cast the Keys enum, and if I cast the WPF Key enum, it will be a different value.

Comment: So just use the KeyInterop Class to convert the WPF Key -> Virtual Key code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.aspx

Comment: `KeyInterop` is the answer, thanks. It's a bit sad that WPF prints Ctrl+Oem1... MenuItem command (with keygesture) binding will by default show Ctrl+Oem1; now I have to override that behavior setting `InputGestureText` manually.

Comment: Terrific! Glad to hear you've got a solution :)