# Get 'Shift' representation of a key in windows

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, shift

Is there a built in way to obtain the equivalent of a key combined with the **Shift** key e.g:

a + **Shift** -> A

1 + **Shift** -> !

I currently have all the keys mapped in a dictionary in pretty much the same way as illustrated above.

I'm using windows forms.

Comment: That depends a bit on the keyboard layout. Not all layouts have the same layout of characters

Comment: That's true and that's a problem, how should I tackle this than @rene?

Comment: I was thinking about [ConsoleKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ConsoleModifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolemodifiers(v=vs.110).aspx) but depends a bit how you want to use it. Can you share an [MCVE] for how intend to use or how you currently use it with the dictionary?

Comment: @rene I would need to include way too much information, the solution I'm using is literally just a `Dictionary<Forms.Keys, string>` this would be a dictionary where there are only "shifted" key values which have the same look as in the question's illustration, without the Shift tho, it's just for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by first calling [vkKeyScan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the  virtual-keycode for the char you're interested in.

With the outcome of that call you can feed [`ToUnicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320(v=vs.85).aspx) to translate what the characters would be when the Shift key is pressed.

Both above mentioned methods are native WinAPI calls in the [KeyBoard and Mouse input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632585(v=vs.85).aspx) category.

Combining above calls and implementing in C# you'll get the following implementation (tested in LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    GetCharWithShiftPressed('1').Dump("1");
    GetCharWithShiftPressed('a').Dump("a");
}

// Inspired on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949520
// TimWi: https://stackoverflow.com/users/33225/timwi
public static string GetCharWithShiftPressed(char ch)
{
    // get the keyscancode 
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx
    var key = Native.VkKeyScan(ch);

    // Use toUnicode to get the actual string shift is pressed
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320(v=vs.85).aspx
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    keyboardState[(int) Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
    var result = Native.ToUnicode(key, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
    if (result == 0) return "No key";
    if (result == -1) return "Dead key";
    return buf.ToString();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
static class Native
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint VkKeyScan(char ch);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ToUnicode(uint virtualKeyCode, 
        uint scanCode,
        byte[] keyboardState,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        StringBuilder receivingBuffer,
        int bufferSize, 
        uint flags);
}
```

Running above code you'll get the following output:

> 1
>      !
>
> a
>      A

This implementation uses the current active keyboard layout. If you instead want to specify alternative keyboard layouts, use the [`ToUnicodeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646322(v=vs.85).aspx) that takes an handle to a keyboardlayout as its last parameter.

The `ToUnicode` handling was borrowed and adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949520/578411) from user [Timwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33225/timwi)

Comment: '[' for example would return an empty result, instead of a curly brace '{'

Comment: @Deadzone not on my box ... what is your keyboard setting? Is it a dead key maybe?

Comment: My keyboard layout is United States International.

Comment: I added extra error handling, can you try that code change and let me know the outcome?

Comment: It doesn't seems to work for any of the control/system keys, it returns a result of 0 for all of them.

Comment: I use the same keyboard layout and when I switched to another the result was different but it still gave me results that seemed reasonable. I can't repro to make it return 0 for control/system keys, assuming you mean the chars like ;:"\|.></? etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148819/discussion-between-deadzone-and-rene).