# PInvoke method that takes char[] of fixed size as input

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a third party lib that has the following signature:

```
int GetError(char *Message, int Length)
```

Here the Message has to be a buffer of at least size Length, otherwise the function fails. How would one PInvoke this? I have tried Stringbuilder for the message, but here I cannot specify the length and the function fails.

The Message parameter is declared as an input parameter to the function.

Comment: StringBuilder has an constructor overload that takes a length, I used it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019129/578411) recently in the `ToUnicode` WinAPI call

Comment: @rene That overload sets the maximum length of the string. But OP wants this `buffer of at least size Length`.

Comment: @SurajS It should still work though

Comment: The other option is to use a `byte[]` and deal with the encoding yourself.

Comment: How would that work? Can you give an example?

Comment: `GetError(new StringBuilder(100), 100)`

Comment: I tried the stringbuilder overload but it gives me an error:
System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274893/1663001

Comment: @DavidG, I meant the byte[] option. What would the PInvoke look like?

Comment: You should use a string builder, but before calling Pinvoke, check the length of the string if it is >= Length

Comment: @SurajS `Message` is most likely an out parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is a routine scenario. You are asking the callee to populate a buffer allocated by the caller. That's the domain of `StringBuilder`.

The p/invoke declaration would be:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.???)]
public static extern int GetError(StringBuilder message, int length);
```

You presumably know what the calling convention is, and can fill it in.

You then call the function like this:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(256);
int retval = GetError(message, message.Capacity);
// check retval for error conditions
string error = message.ToString();
```

Comment: Hehe this is why I linked to your answer in the comments above :)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am getting an error: 
'System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: Likely the problem is that the details are not as you have described in the question. If you create a simple C++ test DLL with a function of the same prototype as that in the question you will find that the code outlined here works fine. Obviously I cannot debug code that I cannot see. Quite often people asking get the details wrong. Check again.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps the fact that the Message parameter is defined as an input parameter is relevant? I was assuming that it was a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: Hard to imagine that it is anything other than an output parameter. It's not const, you specify a length. Surely a string is returned to the caller. No?

Comment: That is what I thought. It is indeed used to be able to read an error message.