# Convert keycode to char/string

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to convert `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` to string/char using :

```
KeysConverter converter = new KeysConverter();
string text = converter.ConvertToString(keyCode);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

But it returned "OemPeriod" for "." and "Oemcomma" for ",". Is there any way to get the exact character?

Comment: Have you tried simple casting like (char) keycode?

Comment: Yes. That wont work for special characters.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` is for use in Winforms apps.

Comment: I cannot guess what `keyCode` is. Could you tell us please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can understand from the question It is `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OK, I agree that almost certainly that is the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably what you really want (bit late, but hope this will help someone else), converting the keycode directly to the character the key prints.

First add this directive into your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(
    uint virtualKeyCode, 
    uint scanCode,
    byte[] keyboardState,
    StringBuilder receivingBuffer, 
    int bufferSize, 
    uint flags
);
```

Then use this if you just want to ignore the shift modifier

```
StringBuilder charPressed = new StringBuilder(256);
ToUnicode((uint)keyCode, 0, new byte[256], charPressed, charPressed.Capacity, 0);
```

Now just call `charPressed.ToString()` to get your key.

If you want the shift modifier, you can use something like this to make it easier

```
static string GetCharsFromKeys(Keys keys, bool shift)    
{
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    if (shift)
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
    }
        ToUnicode((uint)keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
        return buf.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Missing a comma after the `keyboardState` parameter in the first code example, but otherwise great.

Comment: @AlanThomas The `MarshalAs` attribute was wrong, I fixed it. And one wonders why bother passing `keyboardState` at all.

Comment: Buggy; It either handles uppercase *OR* lowercase letters and **not both**.

Answer (score 15):

What you are trying to achieve is no trivial task by any means. There is the keyboard mapping (keyboard layout) that windows (for example) uses to translate keyboard keys to actual characters. Here is how I was able to achieve this:

```
    public string KeyCodeToUnicode(Keys key)
    {
        byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];
        bool keyboardStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

        if (!keyboardStateStatus)
        {
            return "";
        }

        uint virtualKeyCode = (uint)key;
        uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(virtualKeyCode, 0);
        IntPtr inputLocaleIdentifier = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        ToUnicodeEx(virtualKeyCode, scanCode, keyboardState, result, (int)5, (uint)0, inputLocaleIdentifier);

        return result.ToString();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);
```

Comment: I agree, this is really not trivial at all. I was looking for this for automated tests, you greatly help, thx

Comment: Excellent solution for me,

Comment: This has two flaws: 1) it calls a ton of functions (like layout, virtual keymap) for every single key.  2) it captures the keyboardstate (for shift/alt/control) after the key was typed. So all those modifiers are wrongly applied to the previous keypress. This is not going to work

Answer (score 1):

since there is "console-application" in your question tags, try this

```
     ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true);

     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(
                   String.Format("You pressed {0}", input.KeyChar));
     Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel take a look at tags!

Comment: Console Application doesn't mean that he's reading from ConsoleWindow. Does `ReadKey` method returns `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` ? OP has `Keys` enum with him! You should note that.

Answer (score -1):

Those are the correct and expected names for the comma and period keys on your keyboard. You can see that clearly from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx). The `KeysConverter` class is behaving as expected and as designed.

If you want to come up with a different name for those keys you can detect them and substitute the name that you desire to use. For instance:

```
string name;
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Oemcomma:
        name = "Comma";
        break;
    case Keys.OemPeriod:
        name = "Period";
        break;
    default:
        name = (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(e.KeyCode);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I guess they wanted the `,` for Oemcomma, and `.` for OemPeriod. Is writing that giant switch-case for every character we can get from a KeyCode is the only way to go…?

Comment: Not nearly as helpful as the answer using `user32.dll`.

Comment: @AlanThomas That depends on what the intention is. Hand's answers gives completely different output from `KeysConverter.ConvertToString` for all characters. According to the question, asker only wanted different output for `Oemcomma` and `OemPeriod`.