# Input for a customizable keyboard shortcut doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to make an input for custom keyboard shortcut:

```
private void textBoxShortcut_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    textBoxShortcut.Text = "";

    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
    {
        var converter = new KeysConverter();
        textBoxShortcut.Text = converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
    }
}
```

But when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> output is `Shift+ShiftKey`, I need only `Shift` as output (only `Modifier`, not `KeyCode`).
Also when I press <kbd>,</kbd> output is `OemSemicolon` but not `,`.
How can I improve my code?
I've tried to add this:

```
if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back && e.Modifiers = 0)
{
    //do logic
}
```

but than it's impossible to enter any combination like <kbd>Shift+A</kbd>, either <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd>.

---

Edit #1: added my own answer below.

Comment: If you guys know how Discord's shortcut input looks like - I want to do something similar.

Comment: See if what I posted is working as expected. I'm also interested to know if you have the chance to test the results using non-US keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
      e.Handled = true;
       // e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textBox1.Text = "";

        if (e.Modifiers==Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode!=Keys.Back)
      {
            var converter = new KeysConverter();
            textBox1.Text = 
            converter.ConvertToString(e.Modifiers+e.KeyValue);
        }
```

Comment: You example works only for `Shift+A` combination, I need to catch all possible keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: as your example     if (e.Modifiers==Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode!=Keys.Back)

Comment: work for all except backspace
           

 if (e.Modifiers==Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode!=Keys.Back)
            {
                var converter = new KeysConverter();
                textBox1.Text = converter.ConvertToString(e.Modifiers+e.KeyValue);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter out the keys using a switch statement:

```
private void textBoxShortcut_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textBoxShortcut.Text = "";

        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
        {
            var converter = new KeysConverter();
            string keyStr = string.Empty;
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Oemcomma:
                    keyStr = "Comma";
                    break;
                case Keys.OemPeriod:
                    keyStr = "Period";
                    break;
                case Keys.ShiftKey:
                    keyStr = "Shift";
                    break;
                case Keys.ControlKey:
                    keyStr = "Ctrl";
                    break;
                case Keys.Menu:
                    keyStr = "Alt";
                    break;
                default:
                    keyStr = converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
                    break;
            }

            textBoxShortcut.Text = keyStr;
        }
}
```

I also found this question, one of the answers implements a way to do this using a win32 API call: [Convert keycode to char/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170259/convert-keycode-to-char-string)

To implement this solution for your particular example add a new static class to your project:

```
public static class User32Wrapper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int ToUnicode(
        uint virtualKeyCode,
        uint scanCode,
        byte[] keyboardState,
        StringBuilder receivingBuffer,
        int bufferSize,
        uint flags);
}
```

Then in your form you can do as follows:

```
if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
{
    var converter = new KeysConverter();
    string keyStr = string.Empty;
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.ShiftKey:
            keyStr = "Shift";
            break;
        case Keys.ControlKey:
            keyStr = "Ctrl";
            break;
        case Keys.Menu:
            keyStr = "Alt";
            break;
        default:
            keyStr = textBox1.Text = GetCharsFromKeys(e.KeyData, (ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift)==Keys.Shift);
            break;
    }

    textBox1.Text = keyStr;
}

private static string GetCharsFromKeys(Keys keys, bool shift)
{
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    if (shift)
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
    }
    User32Wrapper.ToUnicode((uint)keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
    return buf.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If `Shift` pressed, output is `ShiftKey`, but I need `Shift` only.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I really can use `switch`. But than I have to filter near 20 keyboard buttons - 3 strings for each = 60 string code. I'm still looking for some more universal.

Comment: I also added the "Alt" key which was showing Alt+Menu instead of Alt.

Comment: I checked, there isn't seem to be a simple solution for this. May be using some win32 API. Good luck anyway ;)

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170259/convert-keycode-to-char-string the second answer (the most voted) implements what you want using a win32 API call.

Comment: I saw that but I'm still trying to implement for winforms

Comment: I implemented it to try it out and I also needed to do some if / switch checks besides implementing the call to User32 so it ends up being more complex than my answer... I updated my answer anyway, I give up now ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some days I decided to let users set only these types of combinations:

- <kbd>(Ctrl || Shift || Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>(letter || number)</kbd>
- <kbd>(Ctrl+Shift || Ctrl+Alt || Alt+Shift)</kbd> + <kbd>(letter || number)</kbd>

I went this code:

```
private void textScreenshotHotkey_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textScreenshotHotkey.Text = "";

        bool shiftMod = ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Shift) != 0);
        bool altMod = ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Alt) != 0);
        bool ctrlMod = ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Control) != 0);

        bool modifiers = false;
        bool letterNumber = false;

        if ((shiftMod & altMod) || (shiftMod & ctrlMod) || (altMod & ctrlMod) || shiftMod || altMod || ctrlMod)
        {
            modifiers = true;
        }

        if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.A & e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z) || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 & e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9))
        {
            letterNumber = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back && modifiers == true && letterNumber == true)
        {
            textScreenshotHotkey.Text = (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
        }
    }
```

I'm still looking for simplify my code and sollution which can handle also these symbols ",", ".", ";", "'", "\", "-", "`", "=".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. As it is, should accept anything that doesn't need a "translation" (like Cancel, Insert...).

I've added F1-F24 keys.

I think that would be a good idea to make a user control out of this.
You could override [`ProcessCmdKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) and all would be probably simpler to manage if you'ld ever need to add more options, having the raw `WindowProc` messages to handle directly.

I'm using [MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx). Probably the most straightforward tool to deal with different keyboad layouts.

```
/*
UINT WINAPI MapVirtualKey(
  _In_ UINT uCode,
  _In_ UINT uMapType
); */

const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x02;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

  private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
      {
          string _Char;
          e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
          string KeyModifiers = string.Join("+", e.Modifiers
                                      .ToString().Split(',')
                                      .Where(s => s != "None"))
                                      .ToUpper();

          if (e.KeyCode >= Keys.F1 & e.KeyCode <= Keys.F24)
          {
              _Char = e.KeyCode.ToString();
          } else {
              _Char = ((char)(MapVirtualKey((uint)e.KeyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR))).ToString();
          }

          TextBox1.Text = KeyModifiers + ((KeyModifiers.Length > 0 && _Char != "\0" ? "+ " : "") + _Char);
      } else {
          TextBox1.Text = "";
      }
  }
```