# C# Transfer Keycode to Keychar

Tags: c#, hook, keypress, keydown, keyup

I know this issue is caused by using "Keydown-Keycode" and not "Keypress-Keychar" but how would I get my Keydown to use Keychar instead? Any thoughts.
Im using a global keyboard hook and the hook only seems to use KeyUp and KeyDown. If you know how I can get a global hook to use KeyPress that would be awesome

```
    private string b = string.Empty;
 
    public void gkhr_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {




       
        s += (char)e.KeyCode;
        b = s; // i made b = s because otherwise it would add two values together
        b = b.ToLower(); // Was able to use A-Z in lowercase here
        s = string.Empty; // cheeky little hack
        MessageBox.Show(b);
```

When I click on keyboard "," it displays "3/4".
Another example being "F1" prints "q"

Link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQ9e.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert keycode to char/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170259/convert-keycode-to-char-string)

Comment: I believe I did already... to clarify above i set "private string s = string.Empty;" so S is the string

Comment: Please correct me if I made some kind of foolish error either

Comment: i don't see reason to hack like that. please give typical examples of keys, that you were not able to get without this hack.

Comment: Using KeyCode the only thing i was able to get was 1-9 and A-Z. Special keys like NUMPAD, F1,F2, [,],;,'
were translated to another value and therefor i couldnt use it like a string.
However, using KeyChar i was able to use everything i couldnt with KeyCode

Comment: ok so using your hack, how could you get string such as F1, F2?

Comment: The reasoning behind why im doing this is im making a keybinds menu. The menu takes the string value from a combobox, put its in a text file and then reads back the text file. Its also seems like im limited to KeyDown and KeyUp which use KeyCode!!!

Comment: i actually dont think KeyChar uses f1,f2 but i dont care about that i just want stuff like NUMPAD, [ , ], ;, ',

Comment: did you try the answers in above linked question?

Comment: think it was a little above my paygrade, im new to c# and had a hard time understanding it

Comment: first copy and run it. if success, then try to understand. you don't have to know all before you make your app running.